# Problem in upcasting in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, upcasting

Could someone please explain why this happening:

```
class Apple {

   String type;

   setType(){
      System.out.println("inside apple class");
      this.type = "apple";
   }

}

class RedApple extends Apple {

    String type;

    setType() {
      System.out.println("inside red-apple class");
       this.type = "redapple";
    }
}

int main {

    RedApple red = new RedApple();
    Apple apple = (Apple) red;
    apple.setType();

}
```

But the output produced is:

```
"inside red-apple class”
```

Why does the `.setType()` method execute the sub-class method, and not the super-class method, even though I am up-casting, as can be seen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because that's how polymorphism works in Java: it always uses the most-derived version of the method, which *overrides* other versions. The only way to get the base-class version is to use `super.setType` within the most-derived override.

Answer (score 2):

It's a basic feature of any OOP language. That's why all deconstructors in C++ should be virtual - to implement polymorphism. To make the appropriate method be called. 
[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) is a good artical to understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

This is polymorphism, you have overridden the method so now whenever you call that method on that object, even if it's cast to a super class, the child-most method will be called.

However, an example of where the upcasting DOES make a difference is here:

```
class MyClass {
    static void doSomething(Apple apple) { System.out.println("Apple"); }
    static void doSomething(RedApple apple) { System.out.println("RedApple"); }
}
...
RedApple apple = new RedApple();
MyClass.doSomething(apple);
MyClass.doSomething((Apple)apple);
```

Output:

```
RedApple
Apple
```

Since we upcast it to an Apple the best matched method is the one with the Apple parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This the how java has been designed to work, which is called Overriding behavior of methods. If you want to have the method in the super class, you can use **method-hiding** i:e static methods both in parent and child class with same signature.